# Assigining value to parameter using variable in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple stored procedure with one parameter `@Name` which I want to replace with another variable.

I am actually looking for SQL injection character and if name contains `--` then it should replace it with blank. The stored procedure shown below, it is executing without an error, but not replacing the string for example let is say user searches for `EXEC John'''select * FROM TEST2 --` which has SQL injection statement in it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStudentDetails
    @Name nvarchar(300)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @Name = REPLACE(@Name ,'--','');
    SET @Name = REPLACE(@Name ,'--','');

    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLENAME 
    WHERE Name LIKE N'%'+ @Name +'%'
END
```

Updated stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStudentDetails
    @Name nvarchar(300)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SafeSearchItem   nvarchar(30);

    SELECT  @SafeSearchItem = REPLACE(@Name ,N'--',N'')
    SET  @SafeSearchItem = REPLACE(@Name ,N'--',N'')

    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLENAME 
    WHERE Name LIKE N'%'+ @SafeSearchItem +'%'
END
```

**EXEC**

```
EXEC John'''select * FROM TEST2 --
```

In the second stored procedure, I am always able to inject SQL - not sure it is my system?

Comment: I think this might be an xy question, as there is no chance of injection in the small SQL statement you have provided. if you're looking for avoid SQL Injection, then post what you're really doing and we can help you with that using a way that isn't trying to avoid the problem using `REPLACE`.

Comment: No amount of "sanitization" is going to prevent SQL injection. If you want to search by name, make the *client* provide the pattern. On the other hand what you typed will scan the entire table without using any index. Use full text searching instead

Comment: @Larmu, This is the mis conception we have about store procedure they dont give us complete protection about SQL Injection, above SP is vunrable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not in that SP there's not. There's no dynamic SQL. You could happily pass `'''; DROP TABLE [TABLENAME]; SELECT '''` and you would just get nothing in the resultset. If the OP shares their actual SP, however, I'm sure it would be possible; but not as it stands.

Comment: @Larnu you are right. It's still a DoS in itself though, because it will result in a full table scan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, We are doing sanitization on input itself but i want to have an extra level inside stored procedure also

Comment: @Learning don't. Sanitization or not you are performing a full table scan. Use a full-text search index instead of `%whatever%`

Comment: Also, @Learning you'll see I gave a intentional example of SQL Injection there, **without** using `--`. Just replacing `--` isn't going to "save" you. You need to parametrise your query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, We dont have an option for Full Text search

Comment: @Learning why?? It's just an index. Are you ready to pay the cost of scanning a large table for each and every search?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, This is the actual store procedure, this is additional option use needs to search student by name also ether are other SP to search by ID, Year, Stream..

Comment: @Learning this doesn't explain why you don't use the *appropriate* query and index type. Anyway, you don't risk an injection attack from this query. You can't make it perform well either. That clause will prevent the server from using any indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Can you share an example as i am not able to understand

Comment: @Learning check about [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search). Full-text search is similar to what Google or any search engine does, searching the entire text of a document/field. This allows accelerated queries like `SELECT candidate_name,SSN   
FROM candidates   WHERE CONTAINS(candidate_resume,”SQL Server”) AND candidate_division =DBA;`. Very roughly, the FTS index shreds the text and indexes individual words

Comment: So I've read your question, and what I'm missing is *the question*. Certainly it will replace the string, and certainly you're not going to find results for that string, and certainly there actually is no SQL injection going on here, but beyond that I don't know what your actual problem is, hence the large comment train with people offering suggestions for how to improve this procedure in various ways.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, If i execute this SP with following `EXEC John'''select * FROM TEST2 --` then i am able to execute also the second part that SELECT... also meaning i can put any query there. You can create same on your system & check, May be it then happens only on my i guess

Comment: You may be calling the stored procedure incorrectly. Specifically, you should use whatever your client library has to supply and fill parameters. If you execute the stored procedure manually from T-SQL, you have to do escaping for the literal yourself. If you do, however, the *procedure itself* has no injection problem: `EXEC GetStudentDetails @name='John''''''select * FROM TEST2 --'` works fine (and returns nothing). Not only is replacing the text inside the procedure pointless, it would do nothing to prevent problems from misquoting the call.

Comment: Think @JeroenMostert is on to something here. The problem isn't the SP, or SQL Server, the problem is the application. The application is suffering the injection. Thus, when the SP is executed the statement `EXEC GetStudentDetails N''; DROP PROC GetStudentDetails; --'` Is being run, not that the parameter `@Name` is being passed the value `N''' DROP PROC GetStudentDetails; --'`.

Comment: Considering that we think the problem, now, might be your application, not your SP, you need to post the code you're using to run the SQL (in your application) and tag the relevant language. if the application is suffering injection, then no amount of changes to the SP will fix the problem; much like closing the barn door doesn't help after the horse has bolted.

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, we can't answer the question, as, well there isn't a question applicable for information we're been provided. There is no risk of injection in the SP we have, thus, there is not answer on how to avoid it.

Anyway, instead, what i'm going to do is show firstly why that SP isn't subject to injection and then change it so it would be, and how the limited "fix" in it could easily be avoided.

Firstly, let's start with a simple table and data (I strongly suggest running any following scripts in a Sandbox environment!):

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE InjectionReady (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), SomeText varchar(500));

INSERT INTO InjectionReady
VALUES ('Here is some text'),
       ('Life is like a box a chocolates'),
       ('Milk Chocolate is my favourite'),
       ('Cheese is dairy product'),
       ('Chocolate is a dairy product'),
       ('Cows say "moo"!'),
       ('English Cat says "Meow"'),
       ('Japanese Cat says "Nyaa"');
GO
```

OK, and now let's create your SP (amended for our object). and then do some tests:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NonInjectionSearch @Wildcard nvarchar(100) AS


    SELECT @Wildcard = REPLACE(@Wildcard ,N'--',N'');
    SET @Wildcard = REPLACE(@Wildcard ,N'--',N'');

    SELECT *
    FROM InjectionReady
    WHERE SomeText LIKE N'%'+ @Wildcard +N'%';

GO
EXEC NonInjectionSearch 'Chocolate';
EXEC NonInjectionSearch '''; DROP TABLE InjectionReady;--';
EXEC NonInjectionSearch '''; DROP TABLE InjectionReady; SELECT ''';
```

No injection. Great! Ok, now for an SP that *could* suffer injection:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InjectionSearch @Wildcard nvarchar(100) AS


    SELECT @Wildcard = REPLACE(@Wildcard ,N'--',N'');
    SET @Wildcard = REPLACE(@Wildcard ,N'--',N'');

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @SQL = N'
    SELECT *
    FROM InjectionReady
    WHERE SomeText LIKE N''%'+ @Wildcard + N'%'';'; --Yes, intentional non parametrisation
    PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC (@SQL);

GO
EXEC InjectionSearch 'Chocolate';
GO
EXEC InjectionSearch '''; CREATE TABLE Injection1(ID int);--'; --This'll fail
GO
EXEC InjectionSearch '''; CREATE TABLE Injection2(ID int); SELECT '''; --Oh! This worked!

GO
```

So, how could you avoid this? Well, Parametrise your dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ParamSearch @Wildcard nvarchar(100) AS

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @SQL = N'
    SELECT *
    FROM InjectionReady
    WHERE SomeText LIKE N''%'' + @pWildCard +''%'';'; --Yes, intentional non parametrisation
    PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@pWildcard nvarchar(500)', @pWildCard = @Wildcard;
GO

EXEC ParamSearch 'Chocolate';
GO
EXEC ParamSearch '''; CREATE TABLE Injection1(ID int);--'; --Won't inject
GO
EXEC ParamSearch '''; CREATE TABLE Injection2(ID int); SELECT '''; --Oh! this didn't inject either
```

Dynamic objects bring another level to this, however, I'll only cover this if required; as it stands (like I said at the start) the question asked can't happen for the scenario we have.

*Clean up:*

```
DROP TABLE Injection2;
DROP PROC ParamSearch;
DROP PROC InjectionSearch;
DROP PROC NonInjectionSearch;
DROP TABLE InjectionReady;
```

Comment: You are creating Parameterised  SP

Comment: @Learning Yes, I did. That's also what you have. `CREATE PROCEDURE GetStudentDetails @Name nvarchar(300)...`. `@Name` is a **parameter** and your query is parametrised: `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE Name LIKE N'%'+ @Name +'%'`. Again `@Name` is a **parameter**. I have no idea what you are trying to say with this comment.

Comment: My simple object in this store procedure is to sanitized the parameter before i use it in the query but it is not working i tried following also `DECLARE @SafeSearchItem   nvarchar(30);
SELECT  @SafeSearchItem = REPLACE(@Name,N'--',N'')
SET  @SafeSearchItem = REPLACE(@Name,N'--',N'')`

Comment: If i use Replace to remove `--` from parameter then query will generate error & will not exceute it but in my case it is always executing the injected query also. that part is driving me crazy

Comment: @Learning As I've said in my comment on the question, I think the problem is your application. The SP you've posted in your Question is not subject to SQL injection, as I have demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: I agree with you may be it is just my system which is still able to inject extra sql.. i have updated my question.. I thing something wrong with my local system

Comment: @Learning you need to post your application code; and tag the relevant language. No amount of changing the SP isn't going to help the matter if the application is suffering the injection.